# For loop returning 0 for all iterations except the last one?

Tags: r, for-loop, normal-distribution

I have to generate 1000 values of M. for each value of M I have to generate 100 samples, on interval form that follow a distribution of N(M,1).

After that I separated each bound of an interval in two lists.One list for the lower bound and a list for the upper bound. After, for each M,  I want to calculate the positive sum of the difference of an interval bound and M.

```
n <- 1000
test_value <- 0
M_values <- sample(seq(-1, 1, length.out=n))
erro <- 0.01

gerar_intervalos <- function(M) {
  amostras <- rnorm(1000, mean=M, sd=1)
  intervalos <- cbind(amostras - erro, amostras + erro)
  return(intervalos)
}

intervalos <- sapply(M_values, gerar_intervalos)


inferiores <- apply(intervalos, 2, min)
superiores <- apply(intervalos, 2, max)

#sign test

Tmin <- vector("numeric", length(inferiores))
for (i in length(M_values)) {
  s <- 0
  for (j in length(inferiores)) {
    if (inferiores[j] - M_values[i] > 0) {
      s <- s + (inferiores[j] - M_values[i])
    }
  }
  Tmin[i] <- s
}

Tmax <- vector("numeric", length (superiores))
for (i in length(M_values)) {
  soma <- 0
  for (j in length(superiores)) {
    if (superiores[j] - M_values[i] > 0) {
      soma <- soma + (superiores[j] - M_values[i])
    }
  }
  Tmax[i] <- soma
}
```

My problem is. When I calculate this difference in the for loop the list returns all zeros in the case of Tmin and all zeros, except the last one in the case of Tmax. What is wrong in my code?

Thank you

Comment: You probably want `seq_along` instead of `length` in your for loop declarations.

Comment: To add to @Hugh’s comment… `length(superiores)` is a single number: `1000`. So `I in length(superiores)` is `for I in 1000`. The loops are doin exactly what you asked them to do, not what you want them to do.  You can easily troubleshoot this sort of problem by `print`ing the value of your loop index inside the loop.

Comment: Problem sovled! Thank you!!